# How to update column (set col1 = col1 + 1) in nodejs mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to include expression in column in mongodb using mongoose

```
models.item.update({
    col1: {$gt: 1, $lt: 20}    
}, {
    col1: // I don't know how to set 'col1 + 1' here
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
models.item.update({col1: {$gt: 1, $lt: 20}}, {$inc : {col1: 1}});
```

Check the documentation of [mongodb $inc operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

Answer (score 3):

In order to increment the `col1` field with `1`, you can use the [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator:

```
models.item.update(
    { col1: {$gt: 1, $lt: 20} }, 
    { $inc : { $col1 : 1 } }
);
```

Comment: Isn't the syntax `$inc: {field: value}`, rather than the other way around?